# Renaming folders and files in subdirectories using text file linux

Tags: linux, file, directory, command, rename

I am trying to rename the files and directories using a text file separated by space.

The text file looks like this:

```
dir1-1 dir1_1
dir2-1 dir223_1
```

My command is as follows:

```
xargs -r -a files.txt -L1 mv
```

This command can rename only folders from `dir1-1` to `dir1_1` and `dir2-1`to `dir223_1`so on but it doesn't rename the files in the subdirectories. The files in the corresponding directories also have these prefix of these directories.

Looking forward for the assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by the "files in the subdirectories"?  If `dir1` moves, then `dir1/dir2/foo` becomes `dir1_1/dir2/bar`, so it certainly is moved.  Are you hoping that `dir1/dir2` gets moved to `dir1_1/dir2_1`?

Comment: Files in the these directories also have names like dir1.txt dir1_extra.gz, so I want to rename everything with dir1 to dir1_1 including the files and their respective directories.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have special characters(space of tab...) in your file/dir names,
try

```
perl_script=$(
echo 'chop($_); $orig=$_;'
while read -r src tgt; do
    echo 'if (s{(.*)/'"$src"'([^/]*)}{$1/'"$tgt"'\2}) { print "$orig $_\n";next;}'
done < files.txt)
find . -depth | perl -ne "$perl_script" | xargs -r -L1 echo mv
```

Remove `echo` once you see it does what you wanted.

Comment: I do have dashes in the name of the files.